# getting post thumbnail with wordpress not working inside plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to show the post thumbnail using a wordpress plugin.

$thepostid contains the post id... If I do the following:

```
            $status .= $thepostid;
```

I get the correct post id for the post.

However, if I try to get the post thumbnail with that variable, It does not work.

```
            $status .= get_the_post_thumbnail( $thepostid , 'medium' );
```

If I use it with the correct post id instead like this:

```
            $status .= get_the_post_thumbnail( 884 , 'medium' );
```

It works...

I don't know where the problem is here...

Comment: Is `$thepostid` an integer, or a string?

Comment: I guess integer.. it echoes e.g 884.. hm could be a string though

Comment: Try [echo gettype( $thepostid )](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php)

Comment: hm does not work. I can't echo here to put it into the variable $status

Comment: If getting the type of that variable "doesn't work"...it doesn't actually contain the post ID. Are you sure it isn't actually `$status` that contains the ID? Also, why don't you just pass `get_the_ID()` or `$post->ID` into the function?

Comment: the function already contains the variable for the post id, so I tried to use that. But get_the_id or post-ID do not work either :/

Comment: for example get_the_title($thepostid); works!

Comment: Why don't you paste more parts of the code, so we can have a better look of what's happening. From my point of view you there's nothing or incorrect data `on $thepostid` at least on that line of code.

Answer (score 0):

Then you should cast the type explicitly.

```
$status .= get_the_post_thumbnail( (int) $thepostid , 'medium' );
```

The first argument of get_the_post_thumbnail takes $post->ID as an Integer value.